# Issues on fetching stock data at specific time in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, stock, google-finance

I want to fetch stock value at specific time(for example 10:00:00) in google sheet.

I'm using the following function but it's not working for me.
`=GOOGLEFINANCE(A4,"price",time(10,00,00))`

It shows an error as `The query has returned no data`

Kindly suggest the way to get it using googlefinance or by any other way.

Thanks.